How do I integrate Jupyterbook and JupyterLab?
I am writing a JupyterBook. In my _config.yml file I have some Latex macros
sphinx:
  extra_extensions:
    - sphinx_proof
  config:
    mathjax3_config:
      tex:
        macros:
          "norm": ["\\left\\lVert#1\\right\\rVert", 1]
          "abs": ["\\left\\lvert#1\\right\\rvert", 1]
          "N": "\\mathbb{N}"
          "R": "\\mathbb{R}"

When I build the book all is fine. However, I edit notebooks using JupyterLab and there the Latex macros are not rendered.
What can I do?
